# apps script - google slide - replaceAllText in table

Tags: google-apps-script, cell, google-forms, google-slides

`Hi !

I'm trying to replace text in all cells in all table of a google slide.
I successed with shapes, but not with tables and cells..

And when i loop in using forEach. I only can reach the two first cells of my table.
If i try to reach all with a for loop or one by one (with getCell(1.0), getCell(2.0) etc...), the function doesn't work anymore.

Here my current code

var slides = deck.getSlides();

```
slides.forEach(function(slide){
    var tables = (slide.getTables());
    tables.forEach(function(table){
      table.getCell(0,0).getText().replaceAllText('{{entreprise}}',entreprise);
      table.getCell(1,0).getText().replaceAllText('{{entreprise}}',entreprise);
    })
})
```

Any help with this will be very much appreciated!

the goal is to automated my google slides and replace some variables. with a google form.

Thanks by advance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal in your question is as follows.

- You want to resolve your current issue of `I'm trying to replace text in all cells in all table of a google slide. I successed with shapes, but not with tables and cells..`.
- You want to replace texts in tables of all slides in the Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set your value. You can set multiple patterns.
  var replaceObj = [
    { "from": "{{entreprise}}", "to": "sample1" },
    ,
    ,
    
  ];

  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  slides.forEach(function (slide) {
    var tables = slide.getTables();
    tables.forEach(function (table) {
      for (var r = 0; r < table.getNumRows(); r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < table.getRow(r).getNumCells(); c++) {
          replaceObj.forEach(({ from, to }) => table.getCell(r, c).getText().replaceAllText(from, to));
        }
      }
    })
  })
}
```

- By this modification, all tables of all slides in Google Slides are used, and the texts in tables are replaced using `replaceObj`.
- In this modification, you can set multiple replace patterns to `replaceObj`.

#### References:

- [getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table#getNumRows())
- [getNumCells()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-row#getNumCells())

Comment: It works well. 
I was so stuck, Thank you so much for your answer and the short delay !!

Comment: @Mickael A Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.